# How to use chrome bluetooth api for spp connection in chrome app

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, google-chrome-app, spp

I am learning to develop chrome apps. I want to develop an app using the chrome bluetooth API. I am referring to https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_bluetooth. I see that all samples here (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/bluetooth-samples) talk about using Generic Attribute Profile (GATT). But I want to use Serial Port Profile (SPP). Is it possible to do this using the chrome app bluetooth APIs. If yes then a sample code would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here's a sample Chrome app providing SPP communications with chrome.bluetoothSocket API: https://github.com/mimetics/Chrome-BTconnect-App

Comment: I have tried the sample code but i get the following error, "connection failed : invalid uuid" . Any suggestion would be very helpful.  Thank you

Comment: I haven't tested on my end yet. Maybe you could reach out to the author?